# Pandas combine multiple csv files

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple csv files that I would like to combine into one df.

They are all in this general format, with two index columns:

```
                                           1     2
CU0112-005287-7 Output Energy, (Wh/h)   0.064   0.066
CU0112-005287-7 Lights (Wh)                0     0

                                            1     2
CU0112-001885-L Output Energy, (Wh/h)   1.33    1.317
CU0112-001885-L Lights (Wh)             1.33    1.317
```

and so on...

The combined df would be:

```
                                           1     2
CU0112-005287-7 Output Energy, (Wh/h)   0.064   0.066
CU0112-005287-7 Lights (Wh)                0     0
CU0112-001885-L Output Energy, (Wh/h)   1.33    1.317
CU0112-001885-L Lights (Wh)             1.33    1.317
```

I am trying this code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

files = glob.glob(r'2017-12-05\Aggregated\*.csv')   //folder which contains all the csv files

df = pd.merge([pd.read_csv(f, index_col=[0,1])for f in files], how='outer')

df.to_csv(r'\merged.csv')
```

But I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: merge() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) instead `merge`:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, index_col=[0,1]) for f in files])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following. I made some changes to the DataFrame combining logic

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

files = glob.glob(r'2017-12-05\Aggregated\*.csv')   //folder which contains all the csv files

df = reduce(lambda df1,df2: pd.merge(df1,df2,on='id',how='outer'),[pd.read_csv(f, index_col=[0,1])for f in files] )

df.to_csv(r'\merged.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way:

Creating a list with the names of csvs:

```
files=listdir()
csvs=list()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        csvs.append(file)
```

concatenate the csvs:

```
data=pd.DataFrame()
for i in csvs:
    table=pd.read_csv(i)
    data=pd.concat([data,table])
```