# Pandas: how to add a dataframe inside a cell of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an empty dataframe like the following:

```
simReal2013 = pd.DataFrame(index = np.arange(0,1,1))
```

Then I read as dataframes some .csv files.

```
stat = np.arange(0,5)
xv = [0.005, 0.01, 0.05]  
br = [0.001,0.005]
for i in xv:
    for j in br:
        I = 0
        for s in stat:
            string = 'results/2013/real/run_%d_%f_%f_15.0_10.0_T0_RealNet.csv'%(s,i,j)
            sim = pd.read_csv(string, sep=' ')
            I += np.array(sim.I)
        sim.I = I / 5
        col = '%f_%f'%(i,j)
        simReal2013.insert(0, col, sim)
```

I would like to add the dataframe that I read in a cell of `simReal2013`. In doing so I get the following error:

`ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 9, placement implies 1`

Comment: you want a *dataframe* inside of the *value of a dataframe*? or do you want a list of values in there?

Comment: I'm not going to judge (lies, I'm judging) but if you are looking to use a `DataFrame` as a container for more `DataFrame`s you're likely doing something wrong and can better capture what you're after with a `MultiIndex` in your columns or index.

Comment: I want a dataframe inside of the value of a dataframe.

Comment: Yeah, I gathered that... I'm suggesting that is a bad idea.

Comment: ok and what could be a good solution in order to read all the at once and then work with the data?

Comment: If the dataframes have similar columns and/or indices, use `pd.concat` to create a compiled dataframe with a `MultiIndex`  One of many answers on the topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/49111125/2336654.  Otherwise, just store them in a dictionary.

Comment: @piRSquared thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, putting a dataframe inside of a dataframe is probably not the way you want to go, but if you must, this is one way to do it:

```
df_in=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3]]*2)
d={}
d['a']=df
df_out=pd.DataFrame([d])
type(df_out.loc[0,"a"])
>>> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Maybe a dictionary of dataframes would suffice for your use.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.at[row.Index, 'Col_name'] = df2.copy()
```

Comment: What is `row` in your code? Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Create df1 and df2:

```
import pandas as pd
df1_values=['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD','EEE', 'FFF', 'GGG']
df1=pd.DataFrame(df1_values)
df1.columns=['name']
df2=df1.copy()
```

Insert df2 in the first cell of df1:

```
df1.at[0, 'name']=df2.copy()
```