# How can i combine all the data from the different .csv files into a single table?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have given 5 CSV file, now I want to combine all the data from these file into one single table.

I have tried pd.concat and .join from pandas so far, can only get only two files combined. so far I've tried the following

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data1 = pd.read_csv('data2.csv)

merge = data.join(data1,lsuffix='_NOM',rSuffix='_NIM')

in the end, I want to have every data side by side in my table.[sample data.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqfEg.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas combine multiple csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49111093/pandas-combine-multiple-csv-files). Searching with `python combine many csv to one dataframe` produces more acceptable Q&A's.

Comment: do all the .csv files contain the same columns?

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.  [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @AshanPriyadarshana yes they all have the same amount of coloumns

Answer (score 0):

You just loop through the directory which contains the `.csv` files. For example, refer below:

```
import glob

df = pd.DataFrame()  # An empty data frame

for filename in glob.glob('./<path to your data files>/*.csv'):
    df_temp = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df = df.append(df_temp)
```